# Rails 4 Bootstrap DatePicker class today not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails4 app using `gem 'bootstrap-sass'`. I'm using the bootstrap datepicker.

This is the Javascript:

```
  $(".datepicker").datepicker
    autoclose: true
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
    orientation: "left top"
```

This is the view code:

```
  <%= f.input :shoot_date, :as => :string, :label => 'Shoot Date:', :input_html => {:class => 'datepicker'}, :wrapper_html => {:style => 'width: 250px'} %>
```

**But, today's date is not highlighted.  In the html, it should have:**

```
<td class="day today">23</td>
```

**But it is:**

```
<td class="day">23</td>
```

The `today` is missing.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

PS - I don't want to default to today's date - just have it highlighted on the calendar

Comment: which bootstrap datepicker are you using please give the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using this bootstrap-datepicker,  https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

You should be doing something like this:

`$('.my-datepicker-class').datepicker({ todayHighlight: true});`

`todayHighlight` is the field you have to set to true

hope it helps!